# How to map “shift” key to “shift” + “capslock” using AutoHotkey?

Tags: keyboard, vim, autohotkey, remapping

I’m using Vim, so I”ve remapped <kbd>capslock</kbd> to <kbd>esc</kbd>. But I still want <kbd>capslock</kbd> sometimes. So I’m wondering to remap <kbd>shift</kbd> to <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>capslock</kbd>:

1. When <kbd>shift</kbd> is used the normal way: Long press and release, it should still work as <kbd>shift</kbd> key changing the typing to upper case.
2. When <kbd>shift</kbd> is tapped (short press and release), it should toggle <kbd>capslock</kbd>.

Is something like this possible? Does anybody know of any AutoHotkey scripts or tips on how to do this they could share?

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: yes, autohotkey is only available on windows I think.

Comment: That's correct. However, since you mentioned Vim, I wasn't sure. I see now that Vim is available for Windows systems too.

Comment: I'm using terminal based vim in cygwin. But gvim is already available on windows.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25877754) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this AutoHotkey script slightly modified from [Elliot DeNolf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25877754):

```
~Shift::
    duration := 0
    If (GetKeyState("Shift","p"))
    {
        start := A_TickCount
        While (GetKeyState("Shift"))
            Sleep, 1
        duration := A_TickCount - start
    }
    if (duration < 100) ;Change this value as needed
        if GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T") = 1
        {
            SetCapsLockState, off
        }
        else if GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T") = 0
        {
            SetCapsLockState, on
        }
    Return
```

If the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is depressed for less than 100 milliseconds and released, it'll toggle the <kbd>CapsLk</kbd> key. Any more than 100 msec and it'll act as a regular modifier key.

If 100 msec is too long, choose an appropriate value in the `if` condition.

Comment: Hi Vinayak, thanks a lot for providing the script. It's working fine for the most of the time. But sometimes when I press down shift key without release it, it will turn on capslock, could you help check?

Comment: Are you saying Caps Lock is turned on when you press down Shift and don't release it?

Comment: yeah, assume capslock is turned off now, the light is out. So I'm testing if it's working hold down shift key by watching the capslock if the light remains turned off. But one out of ten times, the light will be turned on, that means the capslock is turned on.

Comment: @AaronShen I cannot reproduce the problem you're facing. Maybe something's wrong with your keyboard? You could try adjusting the delay to something more comfortable for you and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi Vinayak, I adjust the key repeat rate, it seems much better now. Thanks