# Does using Fn key frequently cause RSI?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, keyboard-layout, rsi

My old laptop's keyboard:

[image: Samsung Q330 keyboard]

My new laptop's keyboard:

[image: Asus UX303LA keyboard]

As you can see, the main difference is the lack of `Home`, `End`, `Pg Up` and `Pg Down` keys on the new keyboard. Instead, one can use them by holding the `Fn` button and using arrow keys.

Now while typing, I use these keys excessively. This means that in the new keyboard, I will press the `Fn` key very frequently. Since the `Fn` key is at the pinky's reach, I have to use my pinky excessively.

Also, to obtain the same functionality, now I have to press two keys instead of one.

My question is, would this behavior cause an RSI or similar undesired issues? If it does, which would be the most sound course of action?

- Return the computer to buy a new one which contains these keys on its keyboard.
- Remap the `Fn` key so that it is on an easier place. (Say, remap it to `Caps Lock`)
- Remap keyboard so that some keys will act as `Home`, `End`, `Pg Up` and `Pg Down` keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this answer with a pinch of salt, since I don't use those keys as often as you.

I'm using a compact wireless keyboard for my desktop, which has similar layout to your new laptop keyboard (single <kbd>Fn</kbd> key at left-bottom row and <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>PageUp</kbd> <kbd>PageDn</kbd> <kbd>End</kbd> keys merged to the cursor keys at right-bottom row). Except, your laptop has smaller cursor keys.

To answer your question by part:

> My question is, would this behavior cause an RSI or similar undesired issues?

May be, if you get used to pressing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key using your pinky. Or unlikely, if you soon feel your pinky is tired or numb to make repeated press on the key (The latter applies to me, but I am less likely to feel so when pressing the larger key i.e. the Left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key).

Rather than the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, I think you might soon feel frustrated to press <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>PageUp</kbd> <kbd>PageDn</kbd> <kbd>End</kbd>  keys which have been merged to the cursor keys, which are quite small.

> If it does, which would be the most sound course of action?

I will vote for the last option, "remap keyboard" for those keys. It is the most sound and doable for users who wish to fix things on own.

**Reviewing course of action**

The first option, "return the computer", is actually depends on you. Besides the keyboard layout, do you have any uncomfortable issues when using your current new laptop? Does the place where you purchase the new laptop has returnable policy?

If you answer "yes" to above questions, then you could choose the first option and get what you want. Although it may be difficult to find separate keys for those, especially on modern notebooks.

The second option is not possible. The <kbd>Fn</kbd> cannot be remapped to another key, according to [this post on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/65/remap-fn-to-another-key). Apparently, the key is handled at hardware level and not software.

The third option is to remap some keys to <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>PageUp</kbd> <kbd>PageDn</kbd> <kbd>End</kbd> keys are definitely doable. But quick googling might hamper your motivation, since there are many suggestions directing to set up key maps and configuration files.

**Decided with third option?**

On Windows, there is a utility called [AutoHotkey](https://superuser.com/tags/autohotkey/info) to remap the keys you want. I haven't used this tool for long time, so I can only quote [this post on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/889039/how-to-map-shift-key-to-shift-capslock-using-autohotkey) as example.

On Linux, I have written [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224308/debian-xfce-keyboard-shortcut-for-home-and-end-keys/225683#225683) on how to simulate key press and assign keyboard shortcut for it, for separate question. The easiest way I know for users on Linux.

Comment: "Although it may be difficult to find separate keys for those, especially on modern notebooks." This. I didn't see a single laptop containing these keys recently. I guess this is (unfortunately for me) a new trend. Furthermore, I haven't seen a laptop with cursor keys that are more widely separated. This means that even if remapping Fn to some good location was possible, still I am in trouble with small cursor keys. I really don't know what to do...

Comment: @Utku When I was searching for my new budget laptop last year, I found only some Lenovo and Dell laptops had normal-size cursor keys. But I ended up with small cursor keys, because I bought other brand at better value with good hardware specs. Besides waiting for other answers here, you may try to [ask a new question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) for "small cursor key hardware/software solution"? Who knows, someone has good answer for that.

Comment: By the way, how is life with small cursor keys? Is yours similar to my cursor keys as well? Don't they cause frustration all the time or did you get used to them in say, a month?

Comment: @Utku I'm mostly using touchpad gestures. For correcting mistakes while typing, I use `Backspace` for some letters or `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Left cursor` and `Delete` for several words. The `Left/Right cursor` (or `Home/End`) keys are small, but still has some empty space above it so won't accidentally hit other keys. I tend to avoid using `Up/Down cursors` (or `PgUp/PgDn`) keys and prefers alternative keys or touchpad instead. In short, you have the choice to decide your own habit.

Comment: I'd updated last paragraph of the answer, to be fair for both Windows and Linux users. I didn't notice the "bias" until just now, my bad.